# GCC complaining about a duplicate definition (where only one exists)

Tags: objective-c, gcc, linker-errors

I just seem to hit one error after another when dealing with larger projects in Xcode. This time, GCC is complaining of a duplicate definition for a struct-printing function - one where it is actually defined (in a different file), and one where it is used (in the driver).

The specific error I'm getting is this:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _fprintConfiguration in
/.../bits.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Block.o and
/.../bits.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bits.o
```

where Block.o contains the definition and bits.o contains the driver.

---

I've done some research on this already, but it seems that every problem exists with people actually defining it twice by virtue of `#include`, but in all my files I only use `#import`. Isn't the `#import` directive supposed to 'intelligently' include files? Are there any other reasons I could be getting this error? Are there any other solutions I can try?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're including the same definition in multiple translation units (both `Block.o` and `bits.o`). To fix this, declare the function `inline` or move the definition to a (single) source (non-header) file.

This is orthogonal to the question of `#include` vs. `#import`. That's about including the same code multiple times in the *same* translation unit.

Comment: Wow, I would never have expected that moving the definition from the header file to the implementation file would make a difference. From my understanding, both `#include` and `#import` essentially _include_ files into one mass mess of a compilation unit and compiles it there. Why would moving the definition out of the header file make a difference, if this is the case?

Comment: Unless... Maybe including it in Block.m made conflicts with the actual target including it with bits.m and that's where the linker threw up. Maybe `#import` isn't as smart as the documentation made it out to be ;)

Comment: @vermiculus, the problem is that when the definition is in the header file, it looks to the linker like the function is defined in two different translation units (both units that include the same header).

Comment: Yeah, it's never an issue if something is _declared_ more than once, but defining it more than once raises ambiguity (even if the definitions are identical (scoping)).